# How to add column in a view using ALTER VIEW in sql Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

INITIAL VIEW CREATED

```
create or replace view concert_view 
as
select concert.concert_id
    from concert, event
where concert.concert_id=event.concert_id;
```

WHEN I TRIED TO ADD COLUMNS USING

```
alter view  concert_view as
select
   cname,edate
   from concert,event
 where concert.concert_id=event.concert_id;
```

I HAVE AN ERROR MESSAGE

alter view  concert_view as
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A View is basically only a SELECT -statement. If you want to add another column to your view, just change the statement on which it is based.
And recreate a view.

Comment: thx for the quick answer. Im new in the field.....

Answer (score 16):

ALTER VIEW is not used in this way. The only options for altering a view are to add/drop/modify constraints or to RECOMPILE the view.

If you want to add columns then just run the CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW statement again with a different select.

Comment: thk u much for the help!

Comment: This is the explanation needed: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW statement again with a different select. The question arise because there are objects that are modified with ALTER [OBJECT_NAME] mainly in in MS SQL. Here is with  CREATE OR REPLACE [OBJECT]

Comment: @briteSponge, but hear me out - Doesn't this drop the permissions on the view as well? (maybe this doesn't matter and maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: This does drop permissions.  You'll have to re-run your `grant` statements.